# How to import ES6 modules in ExtjS 6/7

Tags: extjs

I haven't found anything related to this topic.

I'd like to import pusher like normally is done with other js frameoworks:

```
npm install pusher-js
```

Then you just import the library:

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
```

or

```
const Pusher = require('pusher-js');
```

Please share good practices to accomplish that in an ExtJS application.

The last resort would be to just include the min file in app.json:
...

```
"js": [            
            {
                "path": "https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js",
                "bundle": true,
                "compress": false
            }
        ], ...
```

Or even worse, put the include in the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if including it using app.json is not what you want you can load it at the time you need it.

Async (onLoad, onError are the promise)

```
Ext.Loader.loadScript({
    url: 'pusher-js',
    onLoad: successFn,
    onError: errorFn,
    scope: this
});
```

Sync (the code will continue, after the file has been loaded)

```
Ext.Loader.loadScriptsSync(url|[url]);
```

*Optional Approach*

If you add `Ext.require` ExtJS will try to load the file and you can use this in your controller.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SomeViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.someview',

    init() {
        // Preload additional functionality
        Ext.require('MyApp.libs.pusher-js');

        // from folder ===> MyApp/app/libs/pusher-js
    }
})
```

OR

Read [this](https://docs.sencha.com/extangular/7.1.0/guides/application_architecture/importing_components_and_classes.html) as a starting point.

Using `app.json` you can get it all prepared as:

```
"js": [            
            {
                "path": "https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js",
                "remote": true
            }
        ], 
...
```

Inside your initialization:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY', {
    cluster: 'APP_CLUSTER'
});
```

This will load the file automatically and you do not have to import it in any way.

Comment: Hi Dinkheller, well, actually I'd like to include it via app.json the proper way, as an npm package, but  haven't found the way to do it.

Using Ext.Loader.loadScript wouldn't be the ES6 style. Anybody out there using external npm packages with ExtJS?

Comment: Hi Dinkheller, relax. I will release you the bounty. I'll give you twice to compensate the delay. I wasn't around these days. I really appreciate your help. Once you get the points, I'll ask you a few other questions, hoping for an answer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I hope the answers help you

Comment: Dinkheller, your solution works but what I want to do is to import library as ES6 module.

Something like this:

"requires": [
        "font-awesome",
         "pusher"
....

Comment: There are two types of requires. As you mention 'font-awesome' it seems you are talking about app.json. If you require something in app.json, it tells your app to look inside the workspace for a package, that can be used. So - if you want pusher to be `required` you have to generate a package, named pusher. Now within that package (which can be remote) you have to add pusher.js to the `js` section (same as I described it above for the app.json.

Comment: I will try to require something alike pusher in a local class tomorrow and answer again, if that is possible.